# nullpointerexception and database not being created

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm banging my head off my table. I just cant seem to figure this out. All I want to do is have a listview populated with items from my SQLite database when an activity is created.

Maybe I'm missing something small, I have no idea at this point and am beyond frustrated. I know the database isn't being created because it is not present in the file explorer.

Here is DatabaseHandler.java:

```
package com.dd.gfit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    // database strings
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gfit.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;   

    // table strings
    public static final String TABLE_ROUTINES = "routines"; 

    // key strings
    public static final String KEY_ROUTINES_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_ROUTINES_NAME = "name";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // create routines table
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ROUTINES + " ("
                    + KEY_ROUTINES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                    + KEY_ROUTINES_NAME + " VARCHAR"
                    + ")");

        // insert test data into routines table
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ROUTINES + " (" + KEY_ROUTINES_NAME + ") VALUES ('Test Routine 1')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ROUTINES + " (" + KEY_ROUTINES_NAME + ") VALUES ('Test Routine 2')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ROUTINES + " (" + KEY_ROUTINES_NAME + ") VALUES ('Test Routine 3')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ROUTINES + " (" + KEY_ROUTINES_NAME + ") VALUES ('Test Routine 4')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ROUTINES + " (" + KEY_ROUTINES_NAME + ") VALUES ('Test Routine 5')");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // do database upgrades here
    }

    public Cursor fetchRoutines() {
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ROUTINES, new String[] {KEY_ROUTINES_ID, KEY_ROUTINES_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        return cursor;
    }

}
```

Here is RoutinesActivity.java:

```
package com.dd.gfit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class RoutinesActivity extends Activity {

    private DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    private Cursor cursor = db.fetchRoutines();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_routines);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // open the database and show the routines
        db.getWritableDatabase();
        displayRoutines();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_routines, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void displayRoutines() {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.listitem_routine, cursor, 
            new String[] { db.KEY_ROUTINES_NAME }, 
            new int[] { R.id.listitem_routine_name });

        ListView routineList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_routines);
        routineList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Here is activity_routines.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RoutinesActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_routines"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is listitem_routine.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_routine_name"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/lorem_routine_item"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_routine_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic_action_edit" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_routine_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic_action_delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What is wrong here? Also, once I get this working, there are buttons within each listview item as you can see by listitem_routine.xml. I want to pass KEY_ROUTINES_ID into the button somehow so that each item can be edited on the fly. Is there a tutorial I can use anyone is aware of or maybe just a snippet?

EDIT:

Here is the log:

```
12-24 02:52:24.429: D/dalvikvm(783): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 7% free 2564K/2732K, paused 68ms, total 69ms
12-24 02:52:24.449: I/dalvikvm-heap(783): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.616MB for 1048592-byte allocation
12-24 02:52:24.559: D/dalvikvm(783): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3585K/3760K, paused 110ms, total 110ms
12-24 02:52:24.659: D/dalvikvm(783): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3585K/3760K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 102ms
12-24 02:52:24.839: D/dalvikvm(783): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3585K/3760K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
12-24 02:52:24.869: I/dalvikvm-heap(783): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.863MB for 2359312-byte allocation
12-24 02:52:24.989: D/dalvikvm(783): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 5889K/6068K, paused 24ms+33ms, total 115ms
12-24 02:52:25.319: D/gralloc_goldfish(783): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-24 02:52:31.950: E/Trace(827): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-24 02:52:32.660: D/dalvikvm(827): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 52K, 7% free 2564K/2736K, paused 25ms, total 28ms
12-24 02:52:32.670: I/dalvikvm-heap(827): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.616MB for 1048592-byte allocation
12-24 02:52:32.710: D/dalvikvm(827): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3585K/3764K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
12-24 02:52:32.760: D/dalvikvm(827): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3585K/3764K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 50ms
12-24 02:52:32.840: D/dalvikvm(827): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3585K/3764K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
12-24 02:52:32.860: I/dalvikvm-heap(827): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.863MB for 2359312-byte allocation
12-24 02:52:33.000: D/dalvikvm(827): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 5889K/6072K, paused 77ms+13ms, total 140ms
12-24 02:52:33.250: D/gralloc_goldfish(827): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-24 02:52:36.120: D/AndroidRuntime(827): Shutting down VM
12-24 02:52:36.140: W/dalvikvm(827): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dd.gfit/com.dd.gfit.RoutinesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.dd.gfit.DatabaseHandler.fetchRoutines(DatabaseHandler.java:51)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.dd.gfit.RoutinesActivity.<init>(RoutinesActivity.java:17)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
12-24 02:52:36.190: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: You forgot to upload the most important infomation which is the log.

Comment: updating my OP with the log now.

Comment: @scarhand : Do yourself a favour...in your `Activity` you name your `DatabaseHandler` as `db` but `db` is used elsewhere in the code to represent an actual database. Rename your `DatabaseHandler` instance as `dbh` or anything other than `db`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
private Cursor cursor = db.fetchRoutines();
```

You cannot call this because it didn't call `onCreate()` yet. `db.fetchRoutines();` will call something from your db. But you have created your db object. 'this' cannot be used because the object didn't construct yet.

```
private DatabaseHandler db = null;
    private Cursor cursor = null;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_routines);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // open the database and show the routines
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        db.getWritableDatabase();

        cursor = db.fetchRoutines();
        displayRoutines();
    }
```

This method

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

is where you create your object.

```
 db.getWritableDatabase();
```

is where you get your db, you can only use db operations after this line.

Comment: how do i properly call oncreate for the DatabaseHandler? this must be the problem. its not calling oncreate therefore not creating the database.

Comment: is there any way i can do this without making the null declarations above onCreate()? Or do I have to do it this way so that it can be used within the other functions of the class?

Comment: Another way is passing the references to other functions as params, but setting them to null declarations seem to be easier.

Answer (score 1):

`this` keyword in  the following line is the reason for your crashing. 
You are using 'this' keyword before object creation.

```
 private DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

Do the following

```
private DatabaseHandler db;   


    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_routines);
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        }
```

Also move the following line to onCreate()

```
private Cursor cursor = db.fetchRoutines();
```

Answer (score 1):

In `DatabaseHandler`, you never assign the value of `db`. So, when you call `db.query()` in `fetchRoutines()`, it crashes.

You need to set your `db` member variable so that you can use it later. Add the following line to the end of `DatabaseHandler.onCreate()`:

```
this.db = db;
```